# Creating a webdriver instance across classes | selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, bdd

Just pitching into Java! Trying to implement BDD style framework...
I'm running into this issue

My Driver.java looks like this:

```
public class Driver {

    public static WebDriver Instance;


    @Before
    public void InitializeTest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
        Instance = new ChromeDriver();
    }


    @After
    public void TearDownTest(Scenario scenario) {
        //close the browser
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {   //take Screenshot
            System.out.println(scenario.getName());
        }

        Instance.close();
    }

}
```

And my Step-definition file:

```
public class MyStepdefs {

    public static String Url = "https://ebay.com/staging/";
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();

    @Given("^I login to Ebay as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void iLoginToEbayAs(String username) throws Throwable {
        Driver.Instance.navigate().to(Url);
        loginPage.setUserName().sendKeys(username);
        loginPage.setPassword().sendKeys("seeeev");
    }
```

Receiving this error:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at Steps.MyStepdefs.iLoginToEbayAs(MyStepdefs.java:4)
> ```
>
> MyStepdefs.java:4 == Driver.Instance.navigate().to(Url);

Help me pass through this!

Comment: You never mentioned what issues you are facing?

Comment: Sorry, Bud! Just updated...

Comment: Which library or testing framework are you using?

Comment: have you imported the driver class?

Comment: Have you tried to set up a brakpoint to "Instance = new ChromeDriver();". Does your code ever get there?

Comment: @murthi Yes, I did

Comment: @AlexeyR. Nope.. It bombs out directly

Answer (score 1):

Your Driver class never gets initialized, I'm betting Instance is null. I think you have at least 2 options, possibly more ways but this is what i'm thinking.

1. Instead of using @Before, which never gets executed because you don't have any test methods in that class, just make that a static "Init" method that you call in order to initialize your Instance variable
2. Make your Driver class an abstract class that your MyStepDefs class extends from. When you run your method iLoginToEbayAs() it will by default call the @Before method in the parent class and initialize your Instance variable as you expected.

Currently if you set a breakpoint in your @Before method I'm betting it's never getting executed hence NPE.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the argument in the step definition. it should be given below.

```
@Given("^I login to Ebay as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void iLoginToEbayAs(String role) throws Throwable {
    Driver.Instance.navigate().to(Url);
}
```

have you imported the driver class?

Comment: Sorry Murthi... Just updated the Step Definition file... I did pass the string

Comment: @Myszsoda There is!

Comment: Hard to say, try: 

1. switch from navigate() to get(), no diffrence, they do exactly same thing, but I prefer get (not a solution)

2. remove static in URL, it is not needed, though most likely not fix either

3. If you imported correctly, shouldn't be there Instance.navigate().to(Url); instead of Driver.Instance.navigate().to(Url);?

4. No more ideas, you can try it with setter and getter.   BTW: page not found